# pyplot - wont plot array in function due to scalar conversion

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I'm trying to run the following code and getting bounced with this error, any idea how to workaround it? Is it having trouble because its a complex function for `Vd` that I am throwing the array into prior to plotting?

```py
m=20 #kg
Ft=300 #N
Fg=-100 #N
F=Ft+Fg
Ar=F/m
Vro=5 #m/s
T=np.arange(0.2,2,.2) #s
R=3 #m
L=8 #m

Vd=(math.sqrt(((L+Vro*T+0.5*Ar*T**2))+L)**2+R**2))/T

plt.plot(T, Vd,'r')
```

Error:

```py
Vd=(math.sqrt(((L+Vro*T+0.5*Ar*T**2)+L)**2+R**2))/T
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

It works if I use `T` as a single integer.

Comment: math.sqrt() don't take a list or array as parameter. Use np.sqrt()

Answer (score 1):

Using the what David told you, this works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m=20 #kg
Ft=300 #N
Fg=-100 #N
F=Ft+Fg
Ar=F/m
Vro=5 #m/s
T=np.arange(0.2,2,.2) #s
R=3 #m
L=8 #m

Vd=(np.sqrt(((L+Vro*T+0.5*Ar*T**2))+L)**2+R**2)/T

plt.plot(T, Vd,'r')
plt.show()
```